# I could not use my keras model for do a prediction because of one hot encoding size error

Tags: python, keras

I just trained my data by using keras.Before adding model i just one hot encoded the entire data for improving accuracy.
My model gives more than 90% accuracy while training.
After trained my neural network i have tried to predict another same type data by using the trained model.When i was trying to predict it gives below error.

```
    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (10, 133) but 
    got array with shape (10, 119)
```

I know ofcourse it was happen because of One hot encoding size.
so friends please tell me if there is any other method to predict the data?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: just check your new input dimensions. it seems it's not looks like your training data

Answer (score 0):

You need to be attentive at two different things.

1. Keras only accepts batch_predictions. For example, if you have an image with size (1024,1024,3), i.e. a RGB image, you cannot feed the image as it is to a neural network. One needs to simulate the batch index. So practically, when you feed an image to your network it corresponds to a batch with one size. People usually use `np.expand_dims(axis = 0)`, this adds the batch axis. **The same is valid for LSTM predictions**.
2. While the first paragraph was written for you to understand this issue of feeding test data, w.r.t to your actual error, it is clear that you do not feed the test data in the same way you feed your training data.

What you should to is to see the exact shape of the data before you use `.fit()` or `.fit_generator()`. **Print it, and feed the exact input shape to your neural network when testing.** Also, do not forget about the batch_size trick!

In your case, your test data needs to have 133 the second dimension, not 119. Make sure that your small amount of data has 133 value on the second dimension; after this it will definitely work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response and however what exactly my problem is when i was trying to predict small amount of data it says the above mentioned errror.

Comment: Then your test data needs to have 133 the second dimension, not 119. Make sure that your small amount of data has 133 value on the second dimension; after this it will definitely work. I will update the answer.

Comment: I'm using ohe hot encoded data that's why i could not manually adjust it size.

Comment: Then the data that you one-hot-encode needs to be of different dimension.

Comment: If the answer contributed to solving your problem, I would be happy if you accepted the answer as solving one.

Comment: Certainly, your answer was really helpful.Thank you so much for take your own time to help me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203307/discussion-between-timbus-calin-and-velmoorthi).